# AngularJS - Angular-Strap and Angular UI on the same project?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-strap

I am using Angular-Strap, but at this of my project I need to set up an accordion with some special behavior that only Angular UI accordion does... so, is there any conflict if I set up both libraries on the same project?

Is there a way to do not download the full library and only the directive for the accordion that I need and if so, how?

And new to Angular. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Angular-ui project has a Bootstrap module that i am sure if compatible with the rest of angular-ui.

try it out: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

this way you do not have to use angular-strap.

Comment: thanks @Born2Code but at this point I can not let my project without Angular-strap, all I need is this accordion for the special behavior it has.